# Can Dynamic Base shear be greater than Static Base shear?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, dynamics

I just modeled a High-rise building of 43 stories with an area of 700 square meter, Using ETABS as a software to model the building I got the Static and Dynamic Base Shear as the image below, my Question is the following:

Is it Reasonable that the dynamic base shear (Specx and Specy) is bigger than the static base shear (Ex and Ey) ? How can i know if this result is logical or not ?
If the result is Correct i don't need to scale the dynamic base shear ?

[image: ETABS Dynamic and Static Base Shear]

Comment: Forgive me if this is completely naive, but it sounds reasonable to me that a dynamic load is bigger than a static one...

Comment: But If that is the case do I need to scale the dynamic base shear to the static base shear ?

Comment: Are you asking if seismic horizontal forces can be larger than wind forces? If this is not the case, we would never design for seismic loads.

Comment: I meant both for seismic loads but with two method static and dynamic, If i can add a question is that in what conditions does the dynamic base shear greater than the static base shear in general?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes it can be greater than the static base shear, and in this case dont scale

Answer (score 0):

It is desirable but as far as Software concern, It is not possible. Something went to wrong with "Response Spectrum Function Defination" I.e. Define period 0 - 0.036, 0.1 - 0.09, and so on.
Also, check Load type is acceleration type or not.
[image]

Comment: Can you give more detail on your answer? The OP asks whether the results are reasonable, your response is that they aren't possible, can you give more justification? Also, you seem to be suggesting that the OP needs to change some settings, can you explain how you deduced that?